# Using JQuery to perform a function on elements with unique rel attribute

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors, lightbox

I am attempting to improve the portability of a bit of code by automatically detecting what values populate the "rel" attribute of a set of links so that I can create multiple image lightboxes on a page. Basically, right now I am pulling data about hotels from a database, and for each hotel I find I am creating a simple image gallery that consists of a JCarousel, and for each JCarousel the images are able to be clicked launching a lightbox containing only images from that set. Here is the code I currently use to accomplish my goal right now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".carousel").jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular',
        visible: 3,
        scroll: 1
    });
    $('a.lightbox[rel=9]').lightBox();
    $('a.lightbox[rel=10]').lightBox();
    $('a.lightbox[rel=11]').lightBox();
    $('a.lightbox[rel=13]').lightBox();
});
```

The problem with the current approach is that if someone else adds a hotel to the database (which will always be the case) the images will appear within the carousel, but will not have the lightbox effect unless I manually add it. This means a fairly significant amount of upkeep if I plan on using this code across multiple websites (which I do).

What I would like to be able to do is detect the unique "rel" attributes for a.lightbox elements, and loop through them in a $.each to apply the lightbox effect. I'm just not sure how to do that. Any advice?

Comment: Hi Bendon, I've got some sneaking suspicion that you don't need to play with the rel attribute. I've seen lightboxes that automagically pull together the related lightboxes for you. But this is really going to depend on the lightbox your using. For example on http://srbart.com/ take a look at the source in firebug, if you change on of the prettyPhoto[murals] to prettyPhoto[test] it'll put it into a seperate gallery for you.

Comment: I may be missing something in your requirements, but if you have `a` tags with the class of lightbox, can you just add lightbox for any tags with that class (i.e., `$('a.lightbox').lightBox();`), or is there some reason you need to only apply to certain `a.lightbox` elements?

Comment: @Alex - Unfortunately leaving the rel attribute off in this case just created one giant lightbox album, which didn't really work for me since each lightbox album was to show images of different hotels.

Comment: @g_thorn: I may not have been terribly clear, but basically when calling .lightbox() on any set of elements, you are more or less creating an album containing those elements. Since I needed a different album for each hotel, I needed to call .lighbox() on multiple image sets one after the other.

Comment: @Brendon, sorry I don't think my comment was very clear. My comment was more around taking a look at alternative lightbox plugins, as the ones I've looked at will automatically create separate galleries for you. Such as using the prettyPhoto light box, however of course this is going to depend on your other requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Object` as a kind of associative array to store the seen `rel` attributes:

```
var rels = {};  // empty object

$('[rel]').each(function() {     // for every element with a 'rel' attribute
    var r = $(this).attr('rel'); // extract the attribute's value
    rels[r] = 1;                 // store a dummy value in the object
});

rels = Object.keys(rels);        // convert the object to an array of its keys
```

Then you can apply your lightbox to each unique `rel` value in turn:

```
$.each(rels, function(index, value) {
    $('.lightbox[rel="' + value + '"]').lightBox();
});
```

NB: `Object.keys` is an ES5 function.  See the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) site for a compatibility function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var $this, rel, rels [9, 10, 11, 13];
$('a.lightbox').each(function(){
   $this = $(this);
   rel = $this.attr("rel");
   if($.inArray(rel , rels) > -1)
     $this.lightBox();
});
```